# Install tensorflow on Windows in a virtual environment using anaconda

Tags: windows, tensorflow, anaconda

I installed tensorflow on windows with anaconda following the tutorial in the official website.
But when I'm trying to import tensorflow on python, I have this error :

```
(tensorflow1) C:\Users\bromy>python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 14:34:30) [MSC v.1900 
64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Le module spécifié est introuvable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\bromy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
% (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_80.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

I installed CUDA 8.0 but it didn't change anything

Do you have any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: Wha's in your %PATH%?

Comment: Can you be more specific plz ? When can I see that ?

Comment: Run `echo %PATH%` in cmd.exe and see if it has a path to the directory with cudart64_80.dll

Comment: I have one path : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\bin\win64\cudart64_80.dll

Comment: @bahrep What am I suppose to do after that plz ?